# Can someone tell me the flow of references in the second printf statement in the given code?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *c[]={"ENTNG", "NST","AMAZI","FIRBE"};
char** cp[]={c+3, c+2, c+1, c};
char ***cpp= cp;
int main() {
    printf("%s",**++cpp);
    printf("%s ",*--*++cpp+3);
    printf("%s",*cpp[-2]+3);
    printf("%s",cpp[-1][-1]+1);
}
```

Comment: Does the 2nd `printf` output "ST"?

Comment: I just wonder why someone would want to know the outcome of such a mess. If this is production code, fire the person who wrote that. If this homework or assignment or whatever, perhaps post the name of your university so that people may know where they are going when they enroll.

Answer (score 4):

```
 char *c[]= {
              "ENTNG", 
              "NST",
              "AMAZI",
              "FIRBE"
            };
```

`*c[]`evaluates to a character, so `c []`  points to characters and `c` is an array of pointer-to-character. The elements of `c`  have been initialized to point to 
the character arrays

```
"ENTNG", "NST", "AMAZI" and "PIRBE"
```

.

```
char** cp[]={c+3, c+2, c+1, c};
```

`**cp[]` evaluates to a character,`*cp[]` is a pointer-to-character, and `cp []`  is a pointer-to-pointer-to-character.  Thus `cp` is an array of pointers to pointer-to-character.  The elements of `cp` have  been initialized to point to the elements of `c`.

```
char ***cpp= cp;
```

`***cpp` evaluates to a character, `**cpp` points to a character, `*cpp` points to a pointer-to-character,and `cpp` points to a pointer-to-pointer-to-character.

```
*(*(++cpp));         // Increment cpp and then follow the pointers 

Op : "AMAZI"

(*(--(*(++cpp))))+3; // Increment cpp,follow  the pointer to cp[2],
                     // decrement cp[2],follow  the pointer to  c[0],
                     // index  3 from  the address in  c[0].

Op : "NG "

(*(cpp[-2]))+3;      // Indirectly reference  - 2  from cpp yielding cp[0],
                     // follow  the pointer to c[3]; 
                     // index  3 from  the address in  c[3].

Op : "BE"

(cpp[-1][-1])+1      // Indirectly reference -1 from cpp yielding cp [1],
                     // indirectly reference  - 1 from 
                     // cp[1] yielding  c[1],index  1 from  the address in c[1].

Op : "ST"
```

The output would be `AMAZING BEST`

---

Source : **The C Puzzle Book**

Answer (score 1):

Well the output is "AMAZING BEST".

You can check the evaluation order using the [operator precedence table for C](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << (**++cpp) ;
// **++cpp =:= **(cpp = cp+1) =:= *(c+2) =:= "AMAZI"
// side-effect: cpp -> cp+1
cout << (*--*++cpp+3) << " ";
// *--*++cpp+3 =:= *--*(cpp = cp+2)+3 =:= *--(cp+2)+3 =:= *(cp[2] = c)+3 =:= "NG"
// side-effect: cpp -> cp+2, cp => {c+3, c+2, c, c}
cout << (*cpp[-2]+3);
// *cpp[-2]+3 =:= **(cp+2-2)+3 =:= *(c+3)+3 =:= "BE", thus print "BE"
cout << (cpp[-1][-1]+1) << endl;
// cpp[-1][-1]+1 =:= *(*(cp+2-1)-1)+1 =:= *(c+2-1)+1 =:= "ST"
return 0;
```