# pointers, double pointers and triple pointers in c

Tags: c++, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone tell me the flow of references in the second printf statement in the given code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638527/can-someone-tell-me-the-flow-of-references-in-the-second-printf-statement-in-the)

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 char *c[] = {"ENTNG","NST","AMAZI","FIRBE"};
 char **cp[] = {c+3,c+2,c+1,c};
 char ***cpp = cp;
 int main(){
 cout<<(**++cpp);
 cout<<(*--*++cpp+3);
 cout<<(*cpp[-2]+3);
 cout<<(cpp[-1][-1]+1);
 return 0;
 }
```

I am trying to understand the concept of pointers, double pointers and triple pointers. Can please somebody tell me how this code works and the concept behind the solution? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Try reading with care a good C programming book. (notice that in C++ raw pointers are often bad style). Read also a C++ programming book. Don't expect us to explain you what pointers are. It is difficult to teach, given that we don't know what you know about programming.

Comment: BTW, that code is pretty horrible. If you're not comfortable with pointers yet, read a book, or find other examples; you'll (hopefully) never find the kind of code you posted outside of obfuscated C contests - don't learn from it.

Comment: Nobody writes code like `*--*++cpp+3`. Ever. Yes, it's valid, but it would never pass a code review in the real world.

Comment: The main question I want to ask is how do third and fourth line in main() work. I know the concepts but I am finding difficulty in this part particularly.

Comment: Ok thanx, i just asked it because Microsoft has asked this question in its test.

Comment: exact dupliate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638527/can-someone-tell-me-the-flow-of-references-in-the-second-printf-statement-in-the

Comment: You would of thought that Microsoft would have realised by now that pointers are not clever. The ability to parse intricate language constructs is not what distinguishes good programmers from bad programmers. If anything I would be suspicious of a programmer who readily understood the above code. I would think that they don't really get it.

Answer (score 2):

A single pointer is that data type which can point to a memory location of a particular data type.. In this case, it is char so we assume it is a char pointer and it can point only to a char variable, that is, it can hold address of a character variable only.
A double pointer can hold the address of a single pointer, and a triple pointer can hold the address of a double pointer.

In your code, the first pointer 'c' is a double pointer which holds cstrings in itself. cstrings are single char pointers. then 'cp' and 'cpp' both are triple  pointers.

As for the rest of the code,it is pretty messed up and looks like a nightmare. You had better read some resource on pointers and basic C++ programming. I would recomment Programming abstractions in c++ by Sir Eric Roberts from Stanford.
Also see [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointers).